# Emacs, opening multiple windows at startup

Tags: macos, emacs

When I start emacs I would like 4 windows to appear and inside each window I would like a buffer to appear as I specify in my .emacs file. Perhaps in the top left window the emacs web browser w3m would appear, in the top right window the python interpreter would appear, the bottom left window, the last used window appears, and for the bottom right window a blank buffer appears.

1. How can I write this functionality in elisp for my .emacs file?
2. Where did you find out this information to answer this question? Did you use the emacs help pages?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you ask for is a common desire among Emacs users. The good news is, there are a number of existing packages that will do what you want. My favorite is workgroups.el. It's remarkably powerful. You can install it with ELPA; here's the GitHub repository, with an excellent readme. The whole package is unusually well-documented.

https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el

Even if your desire is to learn how to code window and buffer manipulations yourself, I think you'll learn more quickly and with better style by studying an existing package.

Comment: Where did you learn about this package? I wish to become more self-sufficient in using emacs.

Comment: I had to download `workgroups2` but what are the basic commands that will give me the functionality that I want?

Comment: From what I can tell I should just manually create the 4 windows I want and save it as a workgroup?

Comment: > From what I can tell I should just manually create the 4 windows I want and save it as a workgroup?

Comment: > From what I can tell I should just manually create the 
 
> 4 windows I want and save it as a workgroup?  
  
Yes. Save your window configuration as the first workgroup (you can have 9). The first workgroup is enabled when you load workgroups.el, by using require() in your init.el or .emacs file. 
  
I think I initially learned about the package on the Emacs Wiki. "Save Emacs window configuration" is a common search on the net. You'll find a lot of different solutions and approaches.

Answer (score 0):

**ACKNOWLEDGMENTS**

I cobbled together a solution from things I found in the following pages:

- Ubuntu Forums user japhyr has done [almost exactly](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340688&p=8409404#post8409404) what you need.
- Various pages from the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org), you may find the [Windows](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWindows) and [Session Management](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement) categories to be particularly interesting.

**NOTES**

- You did not specify which operating system you are using. I will assume it is some flavor of *nix. Correct me if I'm wrong. If you are using Windows, you can still use the `.emacs` tweaks I am suggesting but cannot use the workaround (see below).
- My solution loads `emacs` with 4 open windows, `w3m` showing google on the top left, a python shell on the top right, the last opened file on the bottom left and an empty `scratch` buffer on the bottom right. This works fine if you launch `emacs` with no arguments but breaks the layout if you open a file directly from the command line:

  ```
  emacs foo.txt
  ```
- I am therefore also suggesting a workaround to load the layout only if no file name has been given. **If you always want to load the 4 window layout, just add the lisp lines below directly to `~/.emacs` instead of creating a new file**.
- If you do decide to add the lines directly to your `~/.emacs` file, be careful with these commands:

  ```
  ;; Set the max number of recent files kept
  (custom-set-variables
   '(recentf-max-saved-items 10)
  '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
  ```

  There can only be one `custom-set-variables` section in an `.emacs` file so instead of adding those lines to the file, find the existing `custom-set-variables` section and just add the variable:

  ```
  '(recentf-max-saved-items 10)
  ```

**ANSWER**

Create a file in your `$HOME` called `.my_emacs_layout` containing these lines (or add them to your `~/.emacs` file, see the notes above):

```
;; Activate recentf mode to get the list of
;; recent files
(recentf-mode 1)

;; Load the w3m browser, change this to the location of your `w3m` install.
;; You should be able to copy the relevant lines from your `~/.emacs`.
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs-lisp/emacs-w3m")
(require 'w3m-load)

;; Set the max number of recent files kept
(custom-set-variables
 '(recentf-max-saved-items 10)
'(inhibit-startup-screen t))
;; Set up initial window layout.  
(split-window-horizontally)
;; Open w3m in the main window, this
;; will be the top left
(w3m-goto-url "www.superuser.com")

;; Split the left window vertically
(split-window-vertically)

;; switch to the bottom left window
(other-window 1)
;; and load the most recent file
(recentf-open-most-recent-file 1)

;; I am sure there is a better way of doing this 
;; but for some reason opening the python shell screws
;; around with the window focus and this ugly hack is 
;; the best I could come up with.
(other-window 1)
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
(other-window 1)
(other-window 1)
;; open the python shell in what will be 
;; the top right window
(py-shell)
```

That's it, you can now load your new `emacs` layout by launching

```
emacs -l ~/.my_emacs_layout
```

**WORKAROUND**

If you want to load a normal `emacs` session when explicitly opening a file and to load the 4 window layout when simply running `emacs`, add these lines to your shell's configuration file (`~/.bashrc` if you are using bash):

```
function emacs(){
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
 then
     /usr/bin/emacs -l ~/.my_emacs_layout
  else
     /usr/bin/emacs "$@"
 fi
}
```

---

Comment: what is `~/.bashrc?` I have a `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I take it you are using a Mac? If so, use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. If you are not on a Mac, create `~/.bashrc`. This is the kind of thing that makes it important to tel us which OS you are using :).

Comment: Yep, Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus if you don't tend to launch emacs from the command line you can ignore my workaround and just add the lines to your `emacs`. It is only a problem when you load files explicitly. even then, it still works, the buffers are there it is just the layout that is screwed up.

Comment: I always launch emacs from the command line...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus in that case, add the function to your .bash_profile. It will disable the 4 pane layout when emacs is called with an argument. If you prefer I can change the .emacs code to open the file passed on the commandline instead of the empty buffer your question asks for.

Comment: I probably won't get around to fully customizing emacs for another month or two. I have a lot of work to do and unfortunately cannot tinker around in emacs as much as I would like to!